# Get reference for my Firebase Query

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm working using Firebase this my database is looking like

[my database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mwEl.png)

```
{
  "CookerInfo" : {
    "org1mLyyJNXtiGo8NimxhWvpId42" : {
      "about" : "Cooker since 2005",
      "address" : "agamy - italy ",
      "available" : "tuesday from 5 am to 9 pm",
      "cookerDishes" : {
        "-Kk3RgXiUEgpgjF1aAdc" : {
          "foodName" : "mol5ia",
          "foodUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-auth-    aa979.appspot.com/o/dishphoto%2F1494723249227.jpg?alt=media&token=0fc03b18-d310-    493a-b332-c1f3e4896567",
          "price" : "8 $",
          "timeToPrepared" : "10 min",
          "weight" : "100 gm "
        }
      },

      "name" : "chef.mohamed",
      "phone" : "0192822228",
      "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-auth-aa979.appspot.com/o/cookerPhoto%2F1494723157098.jpg?alt=media&token=19e4e376-0013-4410-bc04-0483aff09902"
    },
    "vuUscH2L7wgtj2N3rGWOOjgv23s2" : {
      "about" : "cookgood",
      "address" : "alexandria",
      "available" : "sunday",
      "cookerDishes" : {
        "-Kk32fy0FO1vtZgm6AOK" : {
          "foodName" : "chiken",
          "foodUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-auth-    aa979.appspot.com/o/dishphoto%2F1494716692079.jpg?alt=media&token=a70ed96e-acbc-45c6-95b7-4811fd8e2e26",
          "price" : "10$",
          "timeToPrepared" : "10 min",
          "weight" : "100gm"
        },
        "-Kk32mfQWiMRLFV2SMo7" : {
          "foodName" : "rise",
          "foodUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-auth-    aa979.appspot.com/o/dishphoto%2F1494716718899.jpg?alt=media&token=6b9007f5-c22e-4ed4-83aa-a80f45e5363f",
          "price" : "8 $",
          "timeToPrepared" : "8 min",
          "weight" : "50 gm"
        }
      },

      "name" : "sherbini",
      "phone" : "01093812681",
      "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fir-auth-aa979.appspot.com/o/cookerPhoto%2F1494716634787.jpg?alt=media&token=2ba72b6d-0af0-4235-bff5-4b706e91486f"
    }
  }
    }
```

And I want to reach to cookerDishes for specific cooker only (1 cooker) to put his dishes in gridview, however I don't save the ID in model.

I tried something like that, but it didn't work.

```
Query queryRef=mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("name")
           .equalTo(COOKERNAME);


   DatabaseReference node =queryRef.getRef();


   node.child("cookerDishes").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

         Iterable<DataSnapshot> children=dataSnapshot.getChildren();

         for (DataSnapshot child : children){




             FoodDish fooddish = new FoodDish();


             String food_name =child.child("foodName").getValue(String.class);
             fooddish.setFoodName(food_name);



             foodList.add(fooddish);

         }

         gv.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

     }
 });
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: I added it , I hope we can reach to the answer , I solved it by another way to add the ID to Cooker Model , but I don't do that , I don't want to add the ID in my model

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your addapter

Comment: I don't think , it's the problem . because addValueEventListener make this automatically . the problem is in retrieving the data maybe and reach to the dishes and get their info

Comment: When you doing a debug, do the callback get called and foodList changes?

Comment: When I;m doing debug , it comes as this loop  for (DataSnapshot child : children) and skip it and go directly to  gv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: In a debug, is DatabaseReference node has a value?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `getRef()` on the query. Instead you should attach the listener directly to the query:

```
Query queryRef=mDatabaseRef
       .orderByChild("name")
       .equalTo(COOKERNAME);

queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot cookerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      DataSnapshot cookerDishes = cookerSnapshot.getChild("cookerDishes"));
      for (DataSnapshot dishSnapshot: cookerDishes.getChildren()) {
         FoodDish fooddish = new FoodDish();
         String food_name =child.child("foodName").getValue(String.class);
         fooddish.setFoodName(food_name);
         foodList.add(fooddish);
     }
```